How do I get content (text) from a searched file using the Microsoft Graph API?
Firstly, I using sdk 4.x version.
I want to create search function from onedrive with graph api.
In the Teams(app) search function case, when I use search function, the apps return info with file's contents and show stress searching keyword.
I want to show that file's contents(Not full text, only including search keyword)
But, the search response are't including content.
So, How can I replace this function? Or Do I wrong use this api?
That is a my search request code.
 var searchResults = await graphServiceClient
     .Drives[driveId2]
     .Root
     .Search(searchQuery)
     .Request()
     .GetAsync();

In graph explorer case(Http request)
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='')

And also, content request case to reponse including ReadTimeout and WriteTimeout

var searchResults = await graphServiceClient
        .Drives[driveId]
        .Items[fileId]
        .Content
        .Request()                   
        .GetAsync();


At first, we have Search API right now to meet your requirement, you might have a look at the link, to see the request content and the response. Then the current document only shows us a sample with SDK v5. Don't forget to add required permission File.Read.All Sites.Read.All or Files.ReadWrite.All Sites.ReadWrite.All if necessary. Here's the codes.
using Microsoft.Graph.Search.Query;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var requestBody = new QueryPostRequestBody
{
    Requests = new List<SearchRequest>
    {
        new SearchRequest
        {
            EntityTypes = new List<EntityType?>
            {
                EntityType.ExternalItem,
            },
            ContentSources = new List<string>
            {
                "/external/connections/connectionfriendlyname",
            },
            Region = "US",
            Query = new SearchQuery
            {
                QueryString = "contoso product",
            },
            From = 0,
            Size = 25,
            Fields = new List<string>
            {
                "title",
                "description",
            },
        },
    },
};

var result = await graphClient.Search.Query.PostAsQueryPostResponseAsync(requestBody);

But since you are trying to use V4 SDK, while I didn't find official sample or other samples for V4 SDK, I think we could have a workaround which sending http request directly instead of using SDK. Since you already used GraphClient in your code, I trust you also have codes similar to codes below which containing EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

Then we can inject ITokenAcquisition in the Controller to generate access token, and use that to call the query API.
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;
    public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
    {
        _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
    }
    
    public async Task IndexAsync(){
        var accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(new string[] { "File.Read.All", "Sites.Read.All" });
        var request ="{{\"requests\": [{{\"entityTypes\": [\"driveItem\", \"listItem\", \"list\"],\"query\": {{\"queryString\": \"contoso\"}]}}";
        var content = new StringContent(request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpReqMesg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query")
        {
            Headers =
            {
                { HeaderNames.Authorization, "Bearer "+ accessToken}
            },
            Content = content
        };
        var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
        var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpReqMesg);
        var res = "";
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            res = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

}

By the way, if you are using Client Credential Flow which doesn't have ITokenAcquisition. We might use code below to generate access token.
var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenantId";
var clientId = "clientId";
var clientSecret = "clientSecret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var token = clientSecretCredential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext).Result.Token;

